# Como acessar pelo JavaScript uma variável do Twig?

Tags: php, twig

Estou criando um autocomplete pra usar no meu sistema e estou usando Twig...

Meu script é bem simples e com algumas pesquisas na internet, foi a isso que consegui chegar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nomes = {{ usuarios | json_encode | raw }};
        $( "#busca" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: nomes
        });
</script>
```